# Services call stacks

Tags: jquery, node.js, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have writen a huge amount of backbone.js models, collections
and most of them content RESTful service calls using URL.

How can i make these URL service calls as central hub, where all the urls are added and all the models / collections refer this central hub for their RESTful calls.

Comment: Not yet...
Need some guidance regarding the above solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a specific model for settings on a recent project and stored the data in an external json file.

**JSON:**

```
{
    "service-1": "http://url.to.service-1",
    "service-2": "http://url.to.service-2"
}
```

**SettingsModel:**

```
var SettingsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'scripts/data/settings.json'
});
```

**Usage:**

```
var settings = new SettingsModel();
settings.fetch({
    success: function() { 
        var model = new MyModel({ url: this.get('service-1') });
    }
});
```